# How can PHP validate strings containing gobbeldy goop?

Tags: php, string, validation

Say someone submit's a comment form on my website with this

`jfaeioafjifuhdafiuafhiuahfeiheuih487qt4h78tq3ht48ihi7a3vvt4hatfja7c4hat4tyhit4ht4ihgkuagebeyhkughukaghkuagrhagkhrkugr`

This is obviously a junk comment that shouldn't be allowed to be posted.
But how can PHP know that this is a junk comment?
How can I detect junk strings like this one with PHP?

Comment: You must first declare a definition for the term "junk comment", then we may be able to help you implement it.

Comment: Do you expect all comments to be in English? You could test for some obvious "words" that occur in almost any comment: one of "the, be, to, of, and, a, ..." - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English for a good list. Chances that a comment is "valid" without any of the top 20 words are probably quite slim.

Comment: @Floris what would be a good way to check a string for these words?

Comment: So you're saying your post should have been rejected here, since it contains obvious nonsense...? (Try and let that one sink in properly.)

Comment: @user3096443 a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is almost certainly "it can't be done reliably". However, if you want to at least make an attempt, you can draw inspiration from the following - split the string into individual words (removing punctuation and whitespace), then test each word against a list of expected words; and accept the comment if at least one frequent word is present:

```
<?php
$goodString = "This is a valid,comment with lots of known words";
$badString = "gobbledigook yuk yuk yakkety yak";
$goodList = array('the','be','to','of','is','he','she','are','in','that','it','have','for','not','on','with','as','you','do','at');

foreach(array($goodString, $badString) as $testString) {
  $goodCount = 0;
  $splitString = preg_split("/\b/", $testString);
  $testArray = array_filter($splitString, create_function('$a','return preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+$/", $a);'));
  foreach($goodList as $word) {
    if (in_array($word, $testArray) !== FALSE) {
      $goodCount = $goodCount + 1;
    } 
  }

  if($goodCount > 0) {
    echo "'".$goodString."' is a reasonable string\n";
  }
  else {
    echo "'".$testString."' does not have any of the test words in it\n";
  }
}  
?>
```

I picked "short frequent words" (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English) (I left off 'I' and 'a' although they are in the top 20), and look to see that at least one of them is in the test string. In reality you might want to increase the list (maybe based on a frequency list of valid comments on your site), then test that you get "at least a certain percentage of known words". That is a more sensitive (and sensible) test than "as soon as I see a dictionary word I accept the comment".

Comment: *@Floris Right, see Aglutinational Aqualividness.* - That would sound like a perfectly good comment in a forum thread (albeit being made up for effect here) and would not pass your test. Just trying to say that in practice filtering by intend and "meaning" is virtually impossible, especially with just a few short lines of PHP.